# How to write a purrr::reduce function with additional arguments in .f

Tags: r, purrr

Consider this simple example which accumulates the occurrences of the word "This" from a string vector:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

sentences <- c("This is a sentence.",
               "This is another sentence.",
               "One more This")

reduce(str_count(sentences, "This"), `+`)         # SUCCESS! Returns 3
```

I'm trying to understand how to write this with `sentences` passed to `reduce` -- my failed attempts:

```
reduce(sentences, str_count, pattern = "This")          # FAILS! unused argument (.x[[i]])
reduce(sentences, ~ str_count, pattern = "This")        # FAILS! Returns signature for str_count()
reduce(sentences, ~ str_count(pattern = "This"))        # FAILS! Argument "string" missing with no default.
reduce(sentences, ~ str_count("This"))                  # FAILS! Returns wrong result, 4.
reduce(sentences, ~ str_count(.x, pattern = "This") + str_count(.y, pattern = "This"))    # FAILS! Returns wrong result, 1.
```

EDIT: For more clarity, consider a `Python` approach:

```
reduce(lambda a, x: a + x.count("This"), sentences, 0)
```

I'd be interested in a similar `R` approach, but I'm not sure if this is possible (?) because `.count` is a method in `Python`.

Comment: Are you expecting the output to be 3 again for all these re-writes? How do you expect the sum to be happing without the reduce? The reduce expects a function that will take at least two parameters ( one for the previous value and one for the current value). I'm not sure what you are really trying to do here. Are you looking for `map(sentences, str_count, pattern = "This")  %>% reduce(\`+\`)`? Otherwise i can't tell what you are trying to reduce here.

Comment: `str_count` is vectorized. So your original approach, or this one: `sentences %>% str_count("This") %>% reduce(`+`) ` look pretty readable to me. What kind of improvement do you want in addition to these?

Comment: @MrFlick attempted to provide additional context with a Python equivalent example.

Comment: @ycw attempted to provide additional context with a Python example, but I think you hinted at "why" this might not be possible as `str_count` is vectorized and not a method/property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the purpose of this exercise is to show how to pass an argument to `str_count` from within reduce then you could do this:

```r
reduce(sentences, function(x, y, p) x + str_count(y, p), p = "This", .init = 0)
#> [1] 3
```

Although I think the existing suggestions in the comments are a more readable way to achieve the same result.  A simpler way to show how to pass an additional argument is to use something like the `str_c` function which takes strings as an argument and returns a string as a result.

```r
reduce(sentences, str_c, sep = "___")
#> [1] "This is a sentence.___This is another sentence.___One more This"

reduce(sentences, str_c, sep = "___") %>% str_count("This")
#> [1] 3
```